# Spring Integration Java DSL with a defined IntegrationFlow - missing data in response and mismatched correlationIds

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using Spring Integration Java DSL with a defined IntegrationFlow. I am seeing behavior where the response is missing pieces of data and the correlationId in the aggregator response does not match the value in the response that is received by calling service.

Background:

I have a JMeter performance test running on a server that uses random data and is running at 600 requests per minute. On my laptop, I have a SoapUI performance test running that hits the same server. The SoapUI project sends requests with the same search criteria (we are doing matching) at a rate of 60 requests per minute. The responses should all contain the same result data.

Approximately 0.5% of the time the response is returned with data missing. In these responses, the correlationId of the response that is logged from the aggregator and the correlationId of the response logged from the calling service (logged after the response is returned to the calling service and has already passed through the aggregator) do not match.

Any idea what is wrong? Please see code snippets below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(.....AServiceConfig.class)
public class ServiceConfig {

@Bean(name = "inputChannel")
public DirectChannel inputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "outputChannel")
public QueueChannel outputChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "transactionLogger")
public ourLogger ourTransactionLogger() {
    return OurLoggerFactory.getLogger("ourAppTrx", new ourLoggerConfig(ourTransactionLoggerKey.values()));
}

public IntegrationFlow ourFlow() {
     return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel())
            .split(splitter(ourTransactionLogger()))
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(getExecutor()))
            .handle(ourServiceActivator, "service")
            .aggregate(t -> t.processor(ourAggregator, AGGREGATE))
            .channel(outputChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean(name = "executor")
public Executor getExecutor()
{
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    return executor;
}
}
//snippet from calling service

public InquiryResponse inquire(InquiryRequest request) {

    inputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(request).build());
    Message<?> msgResponse = outputChannel.receive();   
    InquiryResponse response = (InquiryResponse) msgResponse.getPayload();
    TransactionLogger.debug("correlationId + msgResponse.getHeaders().get("correlationId"));
    TransactionLogger.debug("InquiryService inquire response = " + response.toString());

    return response;
}

//snippet from aggregator

@Aggregator
public <T> InquiryResponse aggregate(List<Message> serviceResponses) {
    InquiryResponse response = new InquiryResponse();
     serviceResponses.forEach(serviceResponse -> {
            Object payload = serviceResponse.getPayload();

            if (payload instanceof AMatchResponse) {
                response.setA(((AMatchResponse) payload).getA());
            } else if (payload instanceof BValueResponse) {
                response.setB(((BValueResponse) payload).getB());
            } else if (payload instanceof BError) {
                 response.setB(new B().addBErrorsItem((BError) payload));
            } else if (payload instanceof AError) {
                response.setA(new A().AError((AError) payload));
            } else {
                transactionLogger.warn("Unknown message type received. This message will not be aggregated into the response. ||| model=" + payload.getClass().getName());
            }

    });
    transactionLogger.debug("OurAggregator.response = " + response.toString());
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, too many custom variables in this equity. We can't say what is the problem since you don't demonstrate your own code. You always can switch on the DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` and observe the journey of the messages

Comment: Hi Artem, 
I have springframework logging set to TRACE and have added my own logging statements. Between the return of the response object from our Aggregator and the time it is received by the InquiryService, it occasionally loses data, the higher the throughput, the more frequently it happens. I'm not sure what your response to my question means exactly. Is there something specific that I can post that will help clarify the problem? Do you see anything glaring in the code I have posted (in the ServiceConfig, Aggregator or InquiryService) that may be causing the problem?

Comment: I mean there is too much custom logic. You really should try to minimize the scope of the problem. Right now it's hard to determine the root of cause because it's already out of Framework components scope. I don't mind, of course, if the problem is somewhere in the aggregator and would be glad to fix it to let to avoid similar problems for other people, but you have to show the simple test-case to reproduce. We can't help via complex target application logic. That is my point for your question

Comment: Alright, thank you, I will try to pinpoint the issue